# Resolve multigesture conflicts for moving an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm having a rectangle (derived from `UIView`). This rectangle has an attached `UITapGestureRecognizer`, `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and an `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`.

These gesture recognizers are used to move the view, zoom it and rotate it.
 However there is a conflict between the recognizers since rotating doesn't work while panning and so on...

I tried the following

```
[self.pincher requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.panner];
```

With this rotating working while panning. How to extend that such the pinching is working either?

**Edit:**

Whats working:
Every gesture recognizer is working on it's own. But in combination there are troubles or let's say I want a different behavior ;) If I pan an object and tap with a second finger on it and pinch, I want to zoom the object - this is **not** working.

However, starting rotating with the second finger works with the code line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol declares the following method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`
You can override this method and return `YES` to have your recognizers working at the same time:

```
self.pincher.delegate = self;
self.panner.delegate = self;

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I've written a simple view controller that implements simultaneous scale, rotate, and pan on a UIView, you can check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mspensieri/95f0d8c72a3779c77665)

Comment: I implement this delegate and it's et for pincher, panner and rotator but this results in the effect described above.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what is happening? Only one gesture recognizer is firing, even with `shouldRecognizeSimultaneously` returning `YES`?

Comment: I've updated the message. Panning and rotating is working simultaneously. Pinchng not. Delegates are set for all recognizers

Comment: @Razer see my updated answer. The gist I link is a view controller with all three working simultaneously

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem was about concating the transformations.